# Rewrite url in source code

Tags: .htaccess

For instance I have a file php, index.php with content as below:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="menu.php">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="howitwork.php">How it work</a></li>
</ul>
```

And I writed .htaccess as below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^menu/?$ menu.php
RewriteRule ^how-it-work/?$ howitwork.php
```

But if I type localhost/menu or localhost/how-it-work it ok, But I want to see link under Menu and How it work also be writed to /menu and /how-it-work, currently it still menu.php and howitwork.php

Another issue, if I have file product.php?action=view&id=123, how could I use htaccess to change it to this localhost/product/123-name-of-topic/

I code and tested on localhost before make it live.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems the requested URLs are `http://mydomain.com/menu/menu.php` or `http://mydomain.com/how-it-work/howitwork.php` according to your rules, but that's just a guess. Try to include an example in your question with complete URLs: Requested and substitution (real).

Comment: Nope. Currentyly my link in menu navigation is: 
http://mydomain/menu.php
http://mydomain/howitwork.php
I want to change to:
http://mydomain/menu
http://mydomain/how-it-work
As I said above, I write htaccess to change it. But just could be access if I type exactly address to address bar of browser. 
I want my source also be change to http://mydomain/menu when I view it on browser, currently it still http://mydomain/menu.php if I hover my mouse on Menu link. Do you get my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i cant understand your question first of all,

the final issue could be solved by using a post method in your form instead of get,

```
<form action="home.php" method="post">
....
....
</form>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: let me explain it: 
I have source code , which coded by php and mysql, hand-code so in the source there is many link like product.php?action=view&id=123 to request product. Now I want to use htaccess to change it to product/view/123-nameproduct. I writed it, and it could be access in browser via URL product/view/123-nameproduct if I type it to address bar. But problem is when you over your mouse to link product, you still see it as product.php?action=view&id=123, how could I change it to new link automatically by using htaccess or another way?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, here is an example:

**MODIFIED**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*howitwork.*$
RewriteRule .* http://mydomain.com/how-it-work  [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*menu.*$
RewriteRule .* http://mydomain.com/menu  [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how about this:
Another issue, if I have file product.php?action=view&id=123, how could I use htaccess to change it to this localhost/product/123-name-of-topic/
with 123-name-of-topic is combined by id and name of topic. How could I got name of topic,
thanks

Comment: I modified the answer according to your previous comment. I am not sure if that's want you want.

Comment: The rules can be tested [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/). ¿Where is located the .htaccess file? Should be in the root directory. Maybe that's the problem. If it is not and you can't move it to that directory, let me know.

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24075648/1.png
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24075648/2.png
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24075648/3.png

and here is content of htaccess.

Options +FollowSymLinks

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*howitworks.*$
RewriteRule .* http://localhost/how-it-work  [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*menu.*$
RewriteRule .* http://localhost/menu  [L,R=301]

I want link in picture #2 also be change to localhost/how-it-work , not localhost/howitworks.php. How could I do it? Or the current click to it, it redirect ok but page not found...

Comment: ¿Did you test the rules at the link? If worked and still don't work in your local server, it is important to find out what's the problem before any other modifications to the .htaccess file.

Comment: yes, I tested it with your link, it work, but no work on my local lol. Let me try to find out the problem

Comment: OK. Add this `RewriteBase /`in the line below `RewriteEngine On`. I think the problem is with .htacces file location. Make sure it is in the root directory (`localhost/`) and check there are no other .htaccess files in other directories while you are testing. Could you copy the URL as shown in the browser address bar and paste it in a comment?